# Component not rendering the updated state after deleting the post

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having some problems with deleting the post in my app. So, after deleting the post, the state should update and the component should re-render, right? So, after deleting my post, component re-renders with the same data. If I refresh, then only the updated data is shown on the page. For example, if I have 3 posts in my app when I delete ONE post, the component re-renders, but still it shows 3 posts. I don't know why this is happening.

Here's my code.

`UserFeed`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { getUserPosts, getCurrentUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Cards from "./Cards"

class UserFeed extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken")
    if (authToken) {
      this.props.dispatch(getCurrentUser(authToken))
      if (this.props && this.props.userId) {
        this.props.dispatch(getUserPosts(this.props.userId))
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render called")
    const { isFetchingUserPosts, userPosts } = this.props
    console.log(isFetchingUserPosts, userPosts)
    return isFetchingUserPosts ? (
      <p>Fetching....</p>
    ) : (
      <div>
        {userPosts &&
          userPosts.map(post => {
            return <Cards key={post._id} post={post} />
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToPros = state => {
  return {
    isFetchingUserPosts: state.userPosts.isFetchingUserPosts,
    userPosts: state.userPosts.userPosts.userPosts,
    userId: state.auth.user._id
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToPros)(UserFeed)
```

`Cards`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { deletePost } from "../actions/userActions"

class Cards extends Component {

  handleDelete = (_id) => {
    this.props.dispatch(deletePost(_id))
  }

  render() {
    const { _id, title, description } = this.props.post
    return (
      <div className="card">  
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="media">
            <div className="media-left">
              <figure className="image is-48x48">
                <img
                  src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                  alt="Placeholder image"
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div className="media-content" style={{border: "1px grey"}}>
              <p className="title is-5">{title}</p>
              <p className="content">{description}</p>
              <button onClick={() => {this.handleDelete(_id)}} className="button is-success">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state
}

export default compose(withRouter, connect(mapStateToProps))(Cards)
```

`deletePost` action

```js
export const deletePost = (id) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "DELETING_POST_START" })
    try {
      const res = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/${id}/delete`)
      dispatch({
        type: "DELETING_POST_SUCCESS",
        data: res.data
      })
    } catch(error) {
      dispatch({
        type: "DELETING_POST_FAILURE",
        data: { error: "Something went wrong" }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

`userPosts` reducer

```js
const initialState = {
    isFetchingUserPosts: null,
    isFetchedUserPosts: null,
    userPosts: [],
    fetchingUserPostsError: null,
    isDeletingPost: false,
    isDeletedPost: false,
    deletingError: false,
  }

  const userPosts = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "FETCHING_USER_POSTS_START":
        return {
          ...state,
          isFetchingUserPosts: true,
          fetchingUserPostsError: null,
        }
      case "FETCHING_USER_POSTS_SUCCESS":
        return {
          ...state,
          isFetchingUserPosts: false,
          isFetchedUserPosts: true,
          userPosts: action.data,
          fetchingUserPostsError: null,
        }
      case "FETCHING_USER_POSTS_ERROR":
        return {
          ...state,
          isFetchingUserPosts: false,
          isFetchedUserPosts: false,
          fetchingUserPostsError: action.data.error,
        }
      case "DELETING_POST_START":
        return {
          ...state,
          isDeletingPost: true,
          deletingError: null,
        }
      case "DELETING_POST_SUCCESS":
        const filteredPostList = state.postList.filter((post) => post._id !== action.data._id)
        return {
          ...state,
          isDeletingPost: false,
          isDeletedPost: true,
          userPosts: filteredPostList,
          deletingError: null,
        }
      case "DELETING_POST_ERROR":
        return {
          ...state,
          isDeletingPost: false,
          deletingError: action.data.error,
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  export default userPosts
```

Comment: Probably not connected but you have two cases the same: 'DELETING_POST_ERROR'

Comment: You have 3 deleteing post here , and one is deleteing the post from the array. Which one are you trying to call here? Do you want to call the delete api and then display that response with the deleted data. or do you just want to filter the array with the deleted data ?

Comment: I want to display a filtered array of posts. @ThanveerShah. I mean the case DELETING_POST_SUCCESS. That's where filtering is happening. So, when I delete the post, `filteredPostList` gets updated. That's what I'm trying to use in `UserFeed` component. But it's not showing the updated array in the component.

Comment: @rrd sorry, I messed up with copy and pasting code here. Fixed it now.

Comment: But why can't I find state.postList.filter . this postLists anywhere else? Arent you supposed to call userPost there ?

Comment: @ThanveerShah where?

Comment: in DELETING_POST_SUCCESS  there is state.postList. but have you defnied it anywhere ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry.now  I changed it to- `const filteredPostList = state.userPosts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.data._id)`, but it's the same result.

Comment: Are you sure the response data has a property of `_id`? If it's undefined or otherwise some mystical value that no other id's equal then you'll *always* get the original array back. Is `Cards` connected to redux?

Comment: I logged in `console.log(res.data)` after axios call and I got the deleted post object. But when I logged in `console.log(res.data._id)`, it's undefined. How? But there's an`_id` property there in that object. It wouldn't log in. Strange

Comment: @DrewReese, yes, `Cards` is connected to the store, but just for the `dispatch` to be available.

Comment: Perhaps then you need to extract from data in the proper format, something like `await data = res.json();`

Answer (score 0):

Delete post action needs to pass on `id` to the reducer upon success.

Delete post action

```
export const deletePost = (id) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "DELETING_POST_START" })
    try {
      const res = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/${id}/delete`)
      dispatch({
        type: "DELETING_POST_SUCCESS",
        data: res.data,
        id
      })
    } catch(error) {
      dispatch({
        type: "DELETING_POST_FAILURE",
        data: { error: "Something went wrong" }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Access `action.id` in user posts reducer

```
case "DELETING_POST_SUCCESS":
  return {
    ...state,
    isDeletingPost: false,
    isDeletedPost: true,
    userPosts: state.postList.filter(post => post._id !== action.id),
    deletingError: null,
  }
```

Comment: No, it's the same. I think `post._id` is undefined, that's why nothing's happening.